# Varnish 4 cache not getting updated

Tags: apache, http, caching, tomcat7, varnish-4

I am Using a varnish 4 cache as a reverse proxy for my tomcat server, the cache is expected to get updated if I pass a pragma=no-cache header in my http request, as I am doing set req.hash_always_miss = true and then passing the request to backend; if the request has pragma=no-cache set.
is there a way to find out when a http endpoint/url was last updated in the cache?
I need to find this, as I suspect, that the cache is not getting updated correctly and giving old response sometimes.

Comment: Maybe check the Age header?

Comment: Marius is right, check the Age header. Also, check your logs, there might be a clue in there (use varnishlog -g request)